# How to sum coordinates in TCL

Tags: tcl, coordinates

I have a data file (*.dat) containing x, y, z coordinates. As following:

```
{26.3612117767334 40.19668960571289 54.13957977294922}
{27.351043701171875 40.57518768310547 54.05387496948242}
{29.48208999633789 42.08218765258789 56.42238235473633}
```

For this file I need to do a math operation as follow:

```
Xi + (Xf-Xi/4) ; Yi + (Yf-Yi/4) ; Zi + (Zf-Zi/4)
```

where "i" is the initial position and "f" the final, meaning that Xi,Yi,Zi are the data on the first line and Xf,Yf,Zf the data on the second.

I need to do these calculation for all the lines in a loop and then stored in a separate file, but I do not have idea how to do it in TCL. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What element is the final position of the last element when it's the initial one?

Comment: In the first step the line1 and 2 would be the initial and final respectively, in the second step it would be the 2 and 3 the initial and final, and so on, like a loop. For example: first 26.31 and 27.351 for X initial and final; second 27.351 and 29.482, the same. I would like to point out that this operation is in order to calculate the quarter point in the trajectory of a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the contents of your file can be treated as a bunch of tcl lists, one per line (so basically a list of lists), parsing it is dead simple.

Something like:

```
set f [open file.dat]
set coords [read -nonewline $f]
close $f

for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $coords] - 1} {incr i} {
    lassign [lindex $coords $i] xi yi zi
    lassign [lindex $coords $i+1] xf yf zf
    set xn [expr {$xi + ($xf - $xi/4.0)}]
    set yn [expr {$yi + ($yf - $yi/4.0)}]
    set zn [expr {$zi + ($zf - $zi/4.0)}]
    puts "{$xn $yn $zn}"
}
```

This skips treating the last line as an initial set of coordinates because there is no next set for it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am a beginner in TCL, but this works perfect for me.

Comment: It's probably wisest to use `4.0` in those divisions so as to make sure that floating point division is used even if the input data looks like integers.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good opportunity to write a mathfunc:

```
proc tcl::mathfunc::f {ai af} {
    expr {$ai * 0.75 + $af}
}

proc transform {file} {
    set fh [open $file]

    # read the first line, aka the initial "previous line"
    gets $fh line
    scan $line {{%f %f %f}} xi yi zi

    # process the rest of the file
    while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {
        scan $line {{%f %f %f}} xf yf zf
        puts "{[expr {f($xi, $xf)}] [expr {f($yi, $yf)}] [expr {f($zi, $zf)}]}"
        lassign [list $xf $yf $zf] xi yi zi
    }

    close $fh
}

transform file.dat
```

outputs

```
{47.121952533721924 70.72270488739014 94.65855979919434]}
{49.9953727722168 72.51357841491699 96.96278858184814]}
```

Comment: Thank your very much for your response dear Glenn. It also worked for me but I do not undestand very well the mathfunc. As I have mentioned, I am starting with TCL language. Thanks again for replying.

Comment: Looking back on it it's a bit of overkill. Nevertheless: the `::tcl::mathfunc` namespace is where functions recognized by the `expr` command live. Note that I created a proc named `tcl::mathfunc::f` and then I can use `f($x, $y)` in the `expr` commands.

Comment: Since you're getting started in Tcl, I highly recommend the [Tcl tutorial](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

I present an alternate method that uses `lrange` to pick the overlapping ranges of sublists that participate (so we can then process them element-wise) and then `lmap` to apply the same transformation expression to each coordinate axis.

```tcl
# Same read-in code as Shawn's answer; it's the easiest way
set f [open file.dat]
set coords [read -nonewline $f]
close $f

foreach Ci [lrange $coords 0 end-1] Cf [lrange $coords 1 end] {
    # I often like to put expressions on their own line for clarity
    puts [list [lmap _i $Ci _f $Cf {expr {
        $_i + ($_f - $_i/4.0)
    }}]]
}
```

(The wrapping `list` call in there puts braces around the result of `lmap`.)